# Node.js http request returning body/msg empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, http

I am trying to use the requestjs package to post data and wait for a response. But I the body response is always undefined.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
      method: "POST",
      baseUrl: "https://255.255.255",
      uri: "/login",
form: { 
      username: "username",
      password: "password",
      autologin: "true"}},
function(body, msg, err){ 
      console.log(body); console.log(msg); 
})
```

Edit: Again, the undefined body was caused by a privacy policy.

Comment: Are you using the correct parameters? It looks like the signature for the callback is `function (error, response, body)`

Comment: can we see what is in your node.js route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with Promise and non-promise request package. As per your example, `$ajax` returns Promiseified response and you directly get the data from the response of the ajax request. You are expecting that `request` package should also give you data directly, which is not correct.

Actually, you can solve your issue in two ways:

**Sol. 1:**
Use proper callback function arguments and you must get data in the third argument of the callback function. Such as:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    method: "POST",
    baseUrl: "https://255.255.255",
    uri: "/login",
    form: {
      username: "username",
      password: "password",
      autologin: "true"
    }
  },
  function (error, httpResponse, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    console.log(httpResponse.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
  });
```

**Sol. 2:**
Use `request-promise` NPM package (download it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)) and get pomisified response. For example:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

const getData = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      baseUrl: "https://255.255.255",
      uri: "/login",
      form: {
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        autologin: "true",
        resolveWithFullResponse: true, // Returns full response. To get only data don't use this property or mark it false.
      }
    };

    // Get whole Response object.
    const response = await request(options);

    // Returns the Promise.Resolve or Reject based on response.
    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 300) {
      const errorMsg = 'Error occurred while POSTing the request. Got status: ' + response.status;
      console.error(errorMsg);

      // Reject the promise. Should be caught.
      return reject(errorMsg);
    }

    const responseBody = response.body;
    console.log(responseBody);

    // Return the response.
    return resolve(responseBody);
  })
}
```

Above implementation will return a promise for the method `getData()` being called.

**NOTE:** The statement `const response = await request(options);` will return whole response object if `resolveWithFullResponse: true,` is used in the `options` JSON object. If you need only response body or data don't mention `resolveWithFullResponse` property in the options or assign value `false` to it. By default the value of `resolveWithFullResponse` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The format for the callback is (err,response,body); maybe that is why you are getting a empty body and response.
[You can refer here for details.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)